# Vue: Import index.js file of components along with individual components

Tags: vue.js, import, components

In Vue is it possible to import an index.js file of components as well as individually imported components into a Vue file? If I simply import one or the other it works, but can't figure out how to import both into one file. I get an error saying it fails to resolve the latter component below.

[image]

Comment: Can you try `components: { ...components, ScheduleEditor }` instead (assuming components is an array of components)

Comment: That's done it, thank you!